# Decrease margins/padding on Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I currently have the Mystile theme installed on: http://beautenature.biz.

I would like to decrease the white margin/padding from the sides and let the green background image come up right to the page content.

I've looked through the CSS style and can't seem to find the right section to edit. The stylesheet is located here: http://beautenature.biz/wp-content/themes/mystile/style.css

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like to do this to the `body` element, but something like this would work:

```
body {
   width: 1064px;
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   padding: 0 20px;
}

#top, .footer-wrap {margin: 0;}
```

I had to use `!important` above to override your current styles. You can easily see what styles are applying (and where they are located) by using your browser's dev tools. For example, inn Chrome, right click on an element and choose Inspect Element. A panel will open up showing you the HTML code and the CSS styles that apply to it.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the width to a % to keep it responsive and put it in a child theme to keep it separate.

Answer (score -1):

The solutions listed didn't work for me, but I found a very easy one, it's the plugin :
Visual Style Editor also named  YellowPencil !

The lite free version can customize all pages margin and padding easily, you don't need to buy the Regular version, it worked like in the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X78cob9eUGA

hope this help css not yet master developpers!